# “The system cannot find the path specified” error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: linux, windows-10, path, mv, jupyter-notebook

I have been given a Jupyter Notebook which was made on a Linux computer and now I'm trying to get it to work on my Windows home computer. The problem comes when using the **!/bin/mv command**.

I have inputed: **!/bin/mv 'C:\Users\Jez\Documents\test.pdb' 'C:\Users\Jez\Documents\test_changed.pdb'**

With an output of: **"The system cannot find the path specified."**

I have played around and have used: **!/bin/mv test.pdb test_changed.pdb** and many other variations (using 2 **\'s** after **C:**, ...) and all get the same output.

Do these commands work on Windows computers or am I getting confused? Is it something to do with the \bin file? I have made the folder accessible by my user and have taken it out of my OneDrive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the command `!/bin/mv` **is specific** to the **linux** computer the notebook was created from. The `!` is used to execute command line commands and the `/` indicates the root directory of the used computer, comparable to `C:\` on windows. `mv` is a linux command, **windows uses** `move` to do the job. You can look it up [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move).

So you would need to replace the `!/bin/mv` with `!move` like so:

```python
!move C:\Users\Jez\Documents\test.pdb C:\Users\Jez\Documents\test_changed.pdb
```

Note that you can also use relative paths here, but you can read all about the move command in the documentation given above.

So whenever you have a `!` in the code you should check if and what command would do the same on windows. It works as if you would type that command into a cmd / powershell prompt that you open on your windows machine, or a terminal when you're on linux.

You can read more about shell commands in IPython [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html), but beware the reference is using Linux/Unix as well.